# How to pass data after page loading to components in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, vue-component

In my project I use `Vue.js` and `Nuxt.js` and I have this page.

This page is settings page, where user can changes his settings. As you can see, this is only one page, where user can switch between tabs.

```js
<template>
  <div class="account-wrapper">

    <div class="avatar" @click="redirect('/account/me')">
      <img class='avatar-box' src="../../../assets/img/testava.jpg" alt="ava">
      <div class="avatar-text">
        <h2 class="nmp">{{ personalSettings.username }}</h2>
        <p class="paragraph opacity nmp">Public profile</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="side-bar">
      <div v-for="item in accountHeaderItems" :key="item.title" class="flex">
        <div v-if="item.active" class="vertical-line" />
        <p :class="[item.active ? 'item item-active' : 'item']" @click="changeSubsection(item)">
          {{ item.title }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <personal-information v-if="currentSection === 'Public account'" :personal-settings="personalSettings" />
    <security-settings v-else-if="currentSection === 'Security settings'" :security-settings="securitySettings" />
    <site-settings v-else />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SecuritySettings from '~/components/pageComponents/settings/SecuritySettings'
import PersonalInformation from '~/components/pageComponents/settings/PersonalInformation'
import SiteSettings from '~/components/pageComponents/settings/SiteSettings'
import { getUserSettings } from "~/api";
export default {
  name: 'Settings',
  components: {
    SecuritySettings,
    PersonalInformation,
    SiteSettings
  },
  data() {
    return {
      accountHeaderItems: [
        { title: 'Public account', active: true },
        { title: 'Security settings', active: false },
        { title: 'Appearance settings', active: false },
        { title: 'Notifications', active: false }
      ],
      currentSection: 'Public account',

      personalSettings: {},
      securitySettings: {},
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) await this.getUsersSettings(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    else await this.$router.push('/')
  },
  methods: {
    async getUsersSettings(token) {
      const userSettings = await getUserSettings(token)

      if (userSettings.status === -1)
        return this.$router.push('/')

      this.personalSettings = userSettings.personalSettings
      this.securitySettings = userSettings.securitySettings
    },
    changeSubsection(item) {
      this.currentSection = item.title
      this.accountHeaderItems.forEach(header => {
        header.active = item.title === header.title
      })
    },
    redirect(path) {
      this.$router.push(path)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is when page loads. When in `async mounted()` I get data I want to pass it to my components. And here is the problem, when I try to do that it seems to work fine, but there is strange behaviour, I always need to switch between tabs, to make data be visible on page.

For example - in `personalSettings` object there is field `first_name`. So, in `personal-information` component in custom `Input` I want to show this data in this way (in mounted I make copy of object to prevent mutations):

```
<Input
  v-model="personalInfo.first_name"
  :title="'First name'"
  :title-class="'small'"
  :additional-class="'small'"
/>
...
props: {
  personalSettings: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {}
  }
},
data() {
  return {
    personalInfo: {},
    loading: false,
    showPopup: false
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.personalInfo = this.personalSettings
},
```

Everything seems to be fine, but, actually, I have to switch to another tab and switch back to this tab to see this data. What's wrong? How can I prevent this behaviour and show data in correct way?

Comment: "in mounted I make copy of object to prevent mutations" - you actually don't, objects are passed by reference in JS. The reason is that personalSettings is empty object at the time when you access it. Either don't render personal-information until data is ready, or use a watcher on personalSettings to copy it once it's available

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks you! Using `watch` it works just perfectly. By the way, could you tell please more about why it happens. It seems like if wouldn't use components, but render it just on this page, it wouldn't happen. Is this just because object references?

Comment: As mentioned, personalSettings is empty object at the time when you access it in mounted, userSettings.personalSettings is a different object that a child is unware of when there's no watcher

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, you can use Store, and emit changes and Data you want to use late.

See: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store